# Parsing sqlite database file to separate xml files

Tags: objective-c, xml, database, sqlite, parsing

Maybe someone had the same moment in iOS development.
I have an iOS app, which save my created text plans in a sqlite file (plans.sqlite), each of this files can be send by email, as pdf file.
I need pars sqlite file and take from it separete plans, whitch was created and witch will be created in fuature and write them in separete xml files.
For example, I have "plans.sqlite", and I need "plans.sqlite, plan1.xml, plan2.xml..."
I found in documentation NSXMLParser class, but I can't understand, how it works, and I can't find some exemples, like that, what I need.
Can someone explain me how it works and what i need to do step by step in code?
Thanks

Comment: [Here](http://codesofa.com/blog/archive/2008/07/23/make-nsxmlparser-your-friend.html) is an example.